# Transaction failed due to lack of gas

Tags: sushiswap

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7851409abf52ed8b239e0cdc5af0a2f0f43de93f401a53319375bc976df903e0

Hi,

My trx failed due to lack of gas.
I want to provide liquidity on sushiswap. I transferred both erc tokens but the last transaction failed.

What do i need to do to complete the transaction ?
Resent ?
New ?

Greetings, Wannes

Answer (score 0):

You should just increase the gas used to around 180,000 and resend, from your wallet transaction history you only approved the contract to transfer tokens and not actually have done so. So just resend the transaction with increased gas used and it should be fine.

Comment: Thx, i use metamask and changed already the gas settings for future transactions. But i don't know how to resend the same transaction

Comment: You cant resent an already sent transaction you have to create a new one

Comment: How do i create a new one that will execute the failed transaction. I was trying to provide liquidity on Sushiswap

Comment: Once a transaction has failed you can not execute it again in any way. The only thing you can do is go to sushiswap and provide liquidity from scratch